# Detect fn and function key simultaneously pressed

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, command-line, python

I am using [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) to try to change what my volume buttons do.

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how I can detect that the <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> keys are being pressed at the same time as the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

Originally I'd planned to combine an <kbd>F11</kbd> keypress detector and an AppleScript that checks for the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

[image]

I haven't been able to find a way in AppleScript to detect the <kbd>fn</kbd> key. Research led me to possible solutions, such as

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c 'import Cocoa; print Cocoa.NSEvent.modifierFlags()'"
```

But this can't distinguish between the different function keys or <kbd>fn</kbd>.

After almost a week trying to figure this out myself I ask you; is there a way to detect in ControllerMate a simultaneous <kbd>fn</kbd> and function key press?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Fn is *not* a typical modifier key - it's not captured by the OS; it's "local" to the keyboard so to speak.  As such, there's nothing to capture.  One way to test, is to "sniff" the packets - look at this program on [GitHub](https://github.com/objective-see/sniffMK).  Try running it and pressing the Fn key.  If it's not recognized, then you can't capture it with anything.

Comment: @allan karabiner elements manages to do it, so it must be possible somehow. I'll have a look over that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this that uses *the awesome* [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements). This has been so useful for me in many situations, and it works here too.

Karabiner *can* detect function keys being pressed, and tell whether it's with or without the <kbd>fn</kbd> key modifier.

We can make our own "Complex modification" that takes advantage of this:

1. Complex modifications are stored in `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications` as json files. Create a file in here with your favourite text editor:

   ```
   vim ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/detect_fn.json
   ```
2. You need to fill the file with your own rules, here's what mine looks like now:

   ```
   {
     "title": "The fn keys can control volume of built-in output even when a multi-output device is being used.",
     "rules": [
       {
         "description": "Map fn volume keys to execute applescript which changes volume of built-in output.",
         "manipulators": [
           {
             "type": "basic",
             "from": {
               "key_code": "f10",
               "modifiers": {
                 "mandatory": [
                   "fn"
                 ]
               }
             },
             "to": [
               {
                 "shell_command": "osascript -e 'set volume alert volume 0' && osascript -e 'set volume (alert volume of (get volume settings))*7/100'"
               }
             ]
           },
           {
             "type": "basic",
             "from": {
               "key_code": "f11",
               "modifiers": {
                 "mandatory": [
                   "fn"
                 ]
               }
             },
             "to": [
               {
                 "shell_command": "osascript -e 'set volume alert volume ((alert volume of (get volume settings)) - 100/16)' && osascript -e 'set volume (alert volume of (get volume settings))*7/100'"
               }
             ]
           },
           {
             "type": "basic",
             "from": {
               "key_code": "f12",
               "modifiers": {
                 "mandatory": [
                   "fn"
                 ]
               }
             },
             "to": [
               {
                 "shell_command": "osascript -e 'set volume alert volume ((alert volume of (get volume settings)) + 100/16)' && osascript -e 'set volume (alert volume of (get volume settings))*7/100'"
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. It should be obvious how you can replace the keys with whichever ones you want, and you can also replace the shell command with any shell command.
4. Add the rule into karabiner-elements by

   1. Starting it up
   2. Choosing "Complex Modifications" from the top
   3. Clicking "(+) Add rule"
   4. Enabling the rule you just defined